# How to close selected TCP in listbox

Tags: vb.net

- I just need to use +1 (users_connection(listbox1.selectedindex +1).Close
- Now it works

I want to close selected TCP connection in ListBox.

I tried this code, but it's not working:

```
Public users_connection(999)
Public active_connections As Integer

' When a new client connect to the server
'...
Dim Stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()

active_connections += 1
users_connection(active_connections) = stream

'Close the connection
users_connection(ListBox1.SelectedIndex).Close()
```

When I try to close the selected connection in ListBox, it gives this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object variable or With block variable not set.'

Comment: Instead of using an array with a static size and having to keep track of how many slots have been filled, use a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) which has a dynamic size, keeps track of the item amount for you and allows you to remove items as well.

Comment: Create a **Class** to hold the connection and override its ToString() method to return what  you want it to display in the ListBox.  Then add instances of that class directly to the ListBox.  Now you can convert the currently selected item to your instance type and call the Close() method.  Done.

Comment: There's one thing I noticed... you are incrementing `active_connections` FIRST, and THEN using that number as the index for the new `stream`... So the possible starting index becomes 1, which is a bit problematic, as ALL Arrays have zero-based indexes, so if the ListBox's first item was selected, then the property will return 0!!! So my tip would be to increment that variable AFTER you add the new item to the Array.